# How do I build an input_fn for Estimator using images stored in a TFRecords file

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there an example of how to construct the `input_fn` needed by `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator` for an image classification model?  My images are stored in multiple TFRecords files.

Using `tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_record_features`, I am able to generate batches of encoded image strings.  However, I don't see an easy way to convert these strings into images.

Comment: Reference the cifar10 example, specifically the input implementation: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) you can use something like below for `mnist` and `fashion-mnist` dataset stored in `train.tfrecords` and `test.tfrecords`.

The conversion to `tfrecords` is done by code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py) and you need to have a parser to get back the original image and label.

```
def parser(serialized_example):
  """Parses a single tf.Example into image and label tensors."""
  features = tf.parse_single_example(
      serialized_example,
      features={
          'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
          'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
      })
  image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
  image.set_shape([28 * 28])

  # Normalize the values of the image from the range [0, 255] to [-0.5, 0.5]
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255 - 0.5
  label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)
  return image, label
```

After having parser the rest is simple, you just need to call `TFRecordDataset(train_filenames)` and then map the parser function to each element so you will get an image and label as output.

```
# Keep list of filenames, so you can input directory of tfrecords easily
training_filenames = ["data/train.tfrecords"]
test_filenames = ["data/test.tfrecords"]

# Define the input function for training
def train_input_fn():
  # Import MNIST data
  dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(train_filenames)

  # Map the parser over dataset, and batch results by up to batch_size
  dataset = dataset.map(parser, num_threads=1, output_buffer_size=batch_size)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
  dataset = dataset.repeat()
  iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

  features, labels = iterator.get_next()

  return features, labels
```

Comment: As a performance improvement, be sure to always perform `map` after `batch` and `repeat` in your input pipeline when using the Dataset API. See https://youtu.be/SxOsJPaxHME